# Django and work with modal window

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

I created site in Django. And have many items in cycle "for", and with opening modal window i'm needed delete needed item.
How i can get id post (in my case "get_post_id") and sent to modal window (div).
but i'm needed to have modal window not in cycle.

Thanks!

My code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#popup4").hide();
    PopUpHide4();
});
function PopUpShow4(){
    $("#popup4").show();
    $(document).keyup(function(ev){
    if(ev.keyCode == 27)
        $("#popup4").hide();
    });
}
function PopUpHide4(){
    $("#popup4").hide();
}
</script>
```

MODAL WINDOW:

```
<div class="b-popup" id="popup4" >
<div class="b-popup-content">
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
<p><center><font color=#000000 size="5"><b>ADD</b></font></center></p>
<input id="id_post_request" value="2" type="hidden" maxlength="1" name="post_request" type="text">
<input id="id_get_post_id" value="{{ item.id }}" type="hidden" maxlength="9999" name="get_post_id" type="text">
<div class="photo" data-title="Remove"><input type="image" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/delete.png" border="0" width="17" height="17"></div>
<input type="button" value="Cancel" ONCLICK="window.location.href='/'" style="height:30px; width:80px" ></center>
</form> 
</div>
</div>
```

calling modal window :

```
<div id="b-container">
<a href="javascript:PopUpShow4()"><div class="photo" data-title="Remove"><input type="image" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/delete.png" border="0" width="17" height="17"></div></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use javascript to pass the needed id to your modal window.
Is there some button in your cycled items to choose the item? Render an item id within a cycled item, bind onclick event to the button and pass the item id to the modal window hidden input.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help!!!

i'm do this)))

Here is code, in case if needed someone)

script :

```
<script>
function PopUpShow4(id){
    document.getElementById('id_get_post_id').value=id; 
    $("#popup4").show();
    $(document).keyup(function(ev){
    if(ev.keyCode == 27)
        $("#popup4").hide();
    });
}
function PopUpHide4(){
    $("#popup4").hide();
}
</script>
```

MODAL WINDOW:

```
<div class="b-popupdel" id="popup4" >
                        <div class="b-popup-contentdel">

                    <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
                            <p><center><font color=#000000 size="5"><b>Confirm Delete</b></font></center></p>
                                <input id="id_post_request" value="2" type="hidden" maxlength="1" name="post_request" type="text">
                                <center><p><font size="2">Are you sure you want to delete this post?</font></p></center>
                                <input id="id_get_post_id" id_get_post_id" type="hidden" maxlength="9999" name="get_post_id" type="text">
                                                        <center><input type="submit" value="Remove" style="height:30px; width:80px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <input type="button" value="Cancel" ONCLICK="PopUpHide4()" style="height:30px; width:80px" ></center>
                </form>    
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

calling modal window :

```
<div style="width:5%; float:right;">

                <div id="b-container">
                <a href="javascript:PopUpShow4({{ item.id }})"><div class="photo" data-title="Remove"><input type="image" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/delete.png" border="0" width="17" height="17" ></div></a>
                </div>


                  </div>
```